# how to provide a Lot/Serial number for the product through xmlrpc in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I have in my code via xmlrpc a function to validate the picking but it asks me to place the batch number of the product. How can I validate that lot?

```
pick_assign = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.picking', 'force_assign',[pick_id[0]])

pick_transfer_create = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer', 'create',[{'pick_id': pick_id[0]}])

pick_done = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer', 'process', [pick_transfer_create],{})
```

this is the error in the output:

```
Fault: <Fault 2: 'You need to provide a Lot/Serial Number for product xxxxxxxxx (WH/PICK/06113)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying to old thread, but in case someone else is looking for solution for the same problem.

You have `stock.move` (Picking order lines) objects related to your `stock.picking`. If product in a `stock.move` is tracked by serial number each `stock.move` should have as many `stock.move.line` objects related to it as it has quantity. You write serial numbers to `stock.move.line`.

Your `stock.picking` is related to `stock.picking.type`. Scenario of writing serials depends on `stock.picking.type` parameter `use_create_lots`.

If `use_create_lots == True` you can simply write your serial number to field `lot_name` field and Odoo creates `stock_production_lot` -objects (serial number object) for you.

If `user_create_lots == False` Odoo excepts that `stock_production_lot`objects already exists in system and refuses create new serial numbers. In that case you have to search `stock.production.lot`objects and link them to `stock_move_line` object by writing it's id to `stock.move.line.lot_id` -field.